# Calling COM methods from unreferenced assemblies

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, com, wmi

I'm migrating an install script from js to vb.net and I'm facing the following problem.
I'm having issues as JS is late-binded so I need to research the datatype returned by each method in order to make the strong typed counterpart in vb.net (or C# for the matter)

In the original js install script, I'm getting to a point where I don't know how to port this 2 calls:

```
var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
var objAccount = objWMIService.Get("Win32_SID.SID='S-1-1-0'");
```

If I leave data type inference, I get COMType, so I can't call the Get method from the generated object.
I *think* I could solve this by using IDispatch, but It's been like 10 years since I used IDispatch and I can't rememeber exactly how to do it.

Also, after further research, I've seen that the internal COM is actually a SWBemServicesEX object, which I don't know what to reference in order to generate a COM interop system.

I would appreciate it a lot, if anyone can provide any ideas or solutions to this issue.

Current vb.NET code is just:

```
Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
```

not sure how to be able to call the Get method from objWMIService, and how to determine what this method actually returns!

Comment: From another answer, I've read that `Type.InvokeMember()` uses the `IDispatch` methods, so you could try it to invoke `Get()` dynamically.

Comment: Try using `Dim objWMIService as Object = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")` instead. Then you can use `Dim objAccount as Object = objWMIService.Get("Win32_SID.SID='S-1-1-0'")`. When doing late-binding, declare everything as an object. You can then step through the code in debug and sometimes see what the return is. Then search for the methods/properties/etc for that type and write your next line. Takes a little work but you don't need references to any dlls. Theres just an assumption that the dll are registered (COM) or in your path that .Net follows (CLR).

Answer (score 0):

I ended doing what Steve says in his answer and it solved the issue for me. I'm not very happy with runtime late binding, but it gets the job done!

for reference:

> Try using Dim objWMIService as Object = GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\cimv2") instead. Then you can use Dim objAccount as Object = objWMIService.Get("Win32_SID.SID='S-1-1-0'"). When doing late-binding, declare everything as an object. You can then step through the code in debug and sometimes see what the return is. Then search for the methods/properties/etc for that type and write your next line. Takes a little work but you don't need references to any dlls. Theres just an assumption that the dll are registered (COM) or in your path that .Net follows (CLR)